# (40k Dark Angels) Are any loyalist Fallen still alive?

Tags: warhammer-40k

I know the hunt for the Fallen is a big part of Dark Angels lore, and I know that a number of Fallen Angels turned fully to Chaos and live full-time in the Warp, where they live forever agelessly. But as I understand it not all the Fallen actually turned to the ruinous powers - plenty of them just turned against the chapter without actually worshipping Chaos.

**10,000 years since the Horus Heresy, are there any of these non-Chaos Fallen still around**? And if so, how? The Blood Angels are the only chapter I'm aware of being exceptionally long lived, and even the oldest of those (like Dante) are meant to be around 1000. Is there any lore that could support any of these guys still being active (stasis pods, life extension tech, etc)?

Comment: I'm not very well-versed in any WH40k lore which isn't part of the tabletop game material. But I have read that mishaps during warp travel are known to lead to time jumps of hundreds or even thousands of years.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Space marines can live forever and have never died from old age.

For the fallen at the battle of Caliban when it was destroyed by a warp storm the fallen were pulled into it and cast through out space and time. For some only days could of past for others it could of been 1000's of years.

Luther himself has captured after the battle and is imprisoned in the rock and is still alive and he was not a full space marine.

**Wibbly Wobbly Timey Wimey Stuff**

The Warp storm that scattered the Fallen was caused by the clash of Astelan, Typhus, Azrael, and Cypher ten thousand years in the future. The traitors wished to bring the Fallen to the present with the Tuchulcha, but were foiled when Azrael confronted them at the Battle of the Caliban System and used the Tuchulcha to scatter all present. However Azrael was not specific enough with the order, and Tuchulcha temporally scattered the Fallen ten thousand years earlier as well.

This is covered in the novel **The Unforgiven**

Comment: Do you have a source for that? I'd forgotten about Luther still being chained in the rock but the Wiki suggests he's held in a stasis field inbetween interrogation sessions - http://warhammer40k.wikia.com/wiki/Luther  (which is I guess indeed a confirmed example for at least one of them - not sure if that tech is available to renegades who're still on the run)

Comment: The warp storm explanation makes a lot of sense, especially in conjunction with the answer above, thanks!

Comment: @Kolyarut updated with some more info on the warp storm.